p5.js - Module not found: Can't resolve '@p5-wrapper/react'
I'm trying to get setup with @p5-wrapper/react using the very minimal example in the readme.
I've attempted using both @p5-wrapper/next and @p5-wrapper/react.
While it's of course installed, I'm consistently faced with Module not found: Can't resolve '@p5-wrapper/react'.
Module not found: Can't resolve '@p5-wrapper/react'
> 1 | import { ReactP5Wrapper } from "@p5-wrapper/react";

sketch.js edited:
import { ReactP5Wrapper } from "@p5-wrapper/react";

function sketch(p5) {
  p5.setup = () => {};
  p5.draw = () => {};
}

export default function Zine() {
  return <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketch} />;
}


package.json edited:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@p5-wrapper/next": "^1.0.3",
    "@p5-wrapper/react": "^4.4.1",
    "next": ">=12.3.4",
    "p5": "^1.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.1",
    "@types/p5": "^1.7.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}


I tried:

Used multiple versions of Node.js
Used both NPM and Yarn
Brought both NPM and Yarn to most recent versions
rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock
Reinstalled
Tried RC versions of packages


If you plan to use this component within a NextJS application, you should instead use our NextJS dynamic implementation instead. To do get started, you can run:
[npm|yarn|pnpm] [install|add] @p5-wrapper/next @p5-wrapper/react
you can find documents in this site
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@p5-wrapper/react

i've definitely installed it, but it's still not working.
the error is pointing here specifically:
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@p5-wrapper/next/dist/next.js:886:22
Module not found: Can't resolve '@p5-wrapper/react'

so it seems like a dependency for the package?
